# nodejs request.url.match(regexp) seems to return a substring of the match in addition to the match

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I tried a piece of code like this

```
var match = req.url.match(/^\/user\/(.+)/)
```

And passed a url like so `"___http://someurl/user/jane"`

as it turned out match was initialized to an array with the following elements

```
match[0]='/user/jane'
match[1]='jane'
```

I would have expected a single element i.e. the first element in `match[0]`. why was the second string returned -it doesn't seem to match the regex.

My experience with JavaScript is minimal and I couldn't find an explanation after some looking around. Appreciate an explanation of this

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), or better, [`RegExp.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) which has the same return value as `String.match` for a regex without the `g` flag:

> The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then
>   one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the
>   text that was captured.

That is, a group between round brackets¹ makes a capturing group. If you only need the full match you can use:

```
var match = req.url.match(/^\/user\/.+/)[0];
console.log(match); //logs: "/user/jane"
```

This will extract the whole match (at index `0`) returning it to the variable `match`, the rest of the array is discarded.

Note: If the regex may not match, you should test to see if it returns a match before extracting the full match to prevent against errors:

```
var match = req.url.match(/^\/user\/.+/);
if (match !== null) {
    match = match[0];
    console.log(match); //"/user/jane"
} else {
    console.log("no match");
}
```

Here's a live demo for fiddling around: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hpyVn/)

I've removed the capturing group as it wouldn't make a difference in this case. Doesn't actually matter, just a micro-optimization.

You can read more about Regular Expressions' capturing groups/backreferences [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

---

¹ Is not always the case, there are modifiers that make it a non-capturing group (`?:`), lookaheads, lookbehinds etc. but these are off-topic. You can find more about these in the site linked above.